# Dependency Injection in React Native modules

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, react-native

We're going through a gradual conversion of my application to React Native.
And I keep getting into problems with Dependency Injection in React Native on iOS.

I have some services in my app I'd like to use in a native module. Currently, they are injected through Typhoon and everything works just fine.

However, react native itself initializes and maintains any native module as a singleton. That prevents me from letting Typhoon initialize them, and so I can't inject dependencies into them.

What can be done? Creating the RCTBridge myself is an option, but feels very low-level, and still need to figure out how to inject it into the UIView in the first place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why your question didn't receive more up-votes; I myself was struggling to answer the same question and thought I should hop on and answer my first StackOverflow question!

Digging around the [RCTBridge class](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h) provided the answer. What you need to do is initialise a RCTBridge manually with an instance of a class that implements the RCTBridgeProtocol (and importantly the method 'extraModulesForBridge'; you could even implement this protocol in your View Controller if you wanted to.

```
// Initialise a class that implements RCTBridgeDelegate
// Be warned, RCTBridge won't store a strong reference to your delegate.
// You should there store this delegate as a property of your initialising class, or implement the protocol in the View Controller itself. 
id<RCTBridgeDelegate> moduleInitialiser = [[classThatImplementsRCTBridgeDelegate alloc] init];

// Create a RCTBridge instance 
// (you may store this in a static context if you wish to use with other RCTViews you might initialise.  
RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:moduleInitialiser launchOptions:nil];

// Initialise an RCTRootView
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc]
                     initWithBridge:bridge
                         moduleName:kModuleName
                  initialProperties:nil];

// Note that your class that implements RCTBridgeDelegate SHOULD implement the following methods and it might look something like this.

// This will return the location of our Bundle
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
    return [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios"];
}

// Importantly, this is the method we need to implement to answer this question
// We must return an array of initialised Modules
// Be warned, I am writing this off of the top of my head, so excuse any syntax errors there might be!
- (NSArray *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
   return @[[OurNativeModule alloc] initWithCustomInitialiser:customDependency]];
}
```

Edit: I added this to the React-native documentation. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#dependency-injection

Comment: I actually discovered this on my own, but could not find a good way to create RCTModules (I think it was RCTModule, it was a while ago) while using Swift, since our entire app is Swift based. However, I might revisit this and just use objective C for the plumbing and write the actual native module in swift. Did you get it working?

Comment: Is there any capability to replace standard native modules like DatePickerIOS with my own implementation which uses something like private API to change picker colors?

Comment: I started down this path (using @jarora's solution in Swift) but found after debugging that React Native does not reliably use the module provided by the module initializer.  The bridge would create a second instance of my module using the default initializer (`init` with no parameters) and then use that instance.  There were also problems using my custom bridge (created in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) after reloads.

Comment: Do someone has an full example of this? I don't get where to place the class? And what to do with the AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 7):

The code above works just fine. Here's the Swift 4 version of the code.

```
@objc(RNModuleInitialiser)
final class RNModuleInitialiser: NSObject {

    //Inject your dependencies here
    init() {

    }

}

extension RNModuleInitialiser: RCTBridgeDelegate {

    func sourceURL(for bridge: RCTBridge!) -> URL! {
        return URL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios")!
    }

    func extraModules(for bridge: RCTBridge!) -> [RCTBridgeModule]! {

        var extraModules = [RCTBridgeModule]()

        //Initialise the modules here using the dependencies injected above

        return extraModules
    }

}
```

When initializing the bridge, pass the moduleInitialiser:

```
//Make sure to hold the strong reference to the moduleInitaliser

self.moduleInitialiser = RNModuleInitialiser()
self.bridge = RCTBridge(delegate: self.moduleInitialiser, launchOptions: nil)
```

Comment: "Make sure to hold the strong reference to the moduleInitaliser"; This solved a refreshing issue in my application. Thanks for that hint

Comment: How does this work into calling it on the React Native end? Do we need to write a bridge this initializer as well? Good to have a full example

Comment: @evanjmg this might help https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#test-what-you-have-built

Comment: The docs don't help - can you update this example with actual dependencies injected into extra modules you've added?

Comment: The link mentions how to do it using RCT_EXPORT_MODULE, https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#module-name @evanjmg

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I used of configuring an external native module generated by react-native-bob-builder and allowing the injection of dependencies to it.

The React-native docs seem incomplete for manual linking for iOS, so I didn't actually follow it 100%, instead, I created a solution based on some other repos I found.

- Added react-native-config.js to disable automatic linking of this external lib for iOS also.

```js
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    ['myLibJSPackageName']: {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
        ios: null, // Disable ios linking
        // Add more platforms to disable auto-linking for them too
      },
    },
  },
};
```

- Add the lib pod to the target

```rb
target 'MyLibExample' do
  pod 'myLibPodSpecName', :path => '../node_modules/myLibJSPackageName' // If this is inside the example app generated by react-native-bob-builder, the path would be :path => '../..' instead, pointing to the podspec
  ...
end
```

- Created a .h header with the init constructors accepting params

```swift
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface MyLibName : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

- (instancetype)initWithParam1:(NSString *)param1 param2:(NSString *)param2;

@end
```

- Add the manual initialization through `extraModulesForBridge` inside `AppDelegate.m`

```swift
#import <myLibNameInsidePodSpec/MyLibName.h> 

static NSString *const moduleName = @"MyLibExample";

...

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = moduleName;

  // Start - Initialize bridge manually
  // Create a RCTBridge instance with the extraModulesForBridge delegate being the AppDelegate itself
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc]
                      initWithBridge:bridge
                          moduleName:moduleName
                    initialProperties:nil];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  // End - Initialize bridge manually

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

// Add this, if does not exists yet.
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  NSMutableArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [NSMutableArray array];

  // Here the lib is initialized with custom params
  MyLibName *instance = [[MyLibName alloc] initWithParam1:@"value1" param2:@"value2"];
  [extraModules addObject:instance];

  return extraModules;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  #if DEBUG
    return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
  #else
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
  #endif
}

...

@end
```

Feel free to change if you find a better solution.